# Chartjs : data labels getting overlapped in smaller datasets using chartjs-plugin-datalabels

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js

I am using the chartjs-plugin-datalabels, and the values overlap while displaying smaller dataset in large charts

[image]

Here is the chartjs-data-plugin configuration

```
options: {
        plugins: {
            datalabels: {
                    color: 'black',
                    clamp:true,
                    display: function(context) {
                        return context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex] >= 1;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

Try setting the display to auto.

The display: 'auto' option can be used to prevent overlapping labels, based on the following rules when two labels overlap:

- if both labels are display: true, they will be drawn overlapping
- if both labels are display: 'auto', the one with the highest data index will
  be hidden.
- If labels are at the same data index, the one with the highest dataset index will
  be hidden.
- If one label is display: true and the other one is display: 'auto', the one with
  'auto' will be hidden (whatever the data/dataset indices)

Visit https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/positioning.html#visibility

Comment: hey, is there anything that you know of that would allow the labels to move slightly away from each other (preferably vertically, if we're dealing with a vertical stacked bar graph, for example) instead of hiding the overlapping ones?

Comment: @Matvey --- What did you do here? I've done something like a particle collision detector elsewhere in the app for tooltips... but it was hairy. Hoping to avoid having to do it on pie charts.

Comment: @SeanHalls I think I just ended up letting it auto-hide overlapping labels...

Comment: I may be late, but how about setting datalabels.rotation: 45 ? then we can see every labels clearly.